# Pony ORM Entity Unidirectional Mapping gives an error

Tags: python, mysql, orm, database-normalization, ponyorm

I have 2 tables. **TableA** & **TableB**

```
TableA

+------+----------------+-----------+
|  id  | some_attribute | tableB_id |
+------+----------------+-----------+
```

**`id`**=primary key

**`some_attribute`**=varchar

**`TableB_id`**=foreign key

```
TableB

+------+----------------+
|  id  | some_attribute |
+------+----------------+
```

**`id`**=primary key

**`some_attribute`**=varchar

### My code:

```
# establish a connection with the database (MySQL)
db = Connection.Connection.connect_db_server_default()


class TableB(db.Entity):
    _table_ = "table_b"
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=False)
    some_attribute = Required(str)


class TableA(db.Entity):
    _table_ = "table_a"
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=False)
    some_attribute = Required(str)
    TableB_id = Set(TableA)
```

> **Gives the following error:**
>
>   pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Reverse attribute for TableA.TableB_id
>   not found

### My Question:

How can the above relationship be recreated, using Pony ORM?
Do entities always need to have bi-directional relationship?

Is there any way at all to achieve **proper** database normalization or will I have to use some different ORM module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that the error here is my own and the answer to this is specified in the Pony-ORM documentation.

I assumed that since **TableB** is independent and is the referenced table, it shouldn't have any kind of mapping from itself to **TableA**. Yet, the [documentation](https://docs.ponyorm.org/relationships.html) specifies:

> *Some mappers (e.g. Django) require defining relationships on one side
>   only. Pony requires defining relationships on both sides explicitly
>   (as The Zen of Python reads: Explicit is better than implicit), which
>   allows the user to see all relationships from the perspective of each
>   entity.*

And from the examples posted at the same section of the documentation:

```
# If we want to allow an instance of OrderItem to exist without
# being assigned to an 'Order', we can define the order attribute as Optional:
class Order(db.Entity):
    items = Set(lambda: Order)

class OrderItem(db.Entity):
    order = Optional(Order)
```

*Even though the way [Pony-ORM](https://docs.ponyorm.org/) works is **completely wrong** in terms of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), it cannot function any other way. A module should never be blindly used, without spending some time first to properly read the documentation.*

### Ethical Lesson

**NE**ver assume. **R**ead your **D**ocumentation.