# Define foreign key on a single attribute - Pony ORM

Tags: python, mysql, ponyorm

Is there a way of assigning a foreign key to a single attribute with Pony ?
As an example let's say these are my 2 entities :

```
class Course(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    semester = Required(int)
    lectures = Set("Lecture")
    PrimaryKey(name, semester)

class Lecture(db.Entity):
    date = Required(datetime)
    course = Required(Course)
```

Now my goal is to only have the `course.name` attribute in my class `Lecture`. Something like this (which doesn't work) :

```
class Lecture(db.Entity):
    date = Required(datetime)
    course_name = Required(Course.name)
```

Do you have any ideas on how this could be done ?

Comment: Cause those are entities not tables you should declare link from both sides. Why don't you want to have that attribute in your Course entity? It gives you an ability to easily work with lectures collection for courses.

Comment: The exact answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580180/pony-orm-entity-unidirectional-mapping-gives-an-error/54583568#54583568)